# Отличие коллекций от массивов

Tags: java, алгоритм

Из практики лучше работать с коллекциями чем с массивами. Но вот конкретно почему не понятно. Потому что коллекции параметризируются объектами, а не примитивами?, так и массивы тоже могут иметь тип добавляемых значений, по массиву можно так же проитерироваться как и по коллекции, также существуют Util классы как для массивов так и для коллекций. Нужен ответ на следующие вопросы:

- Чем коллекции лучше массивов?
- В чем преимущества коллекций над массивами?
- Когда лучше использовать массивы, чем коллекции?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вы путаете понятия. Если вам достаточно функционала массива, то используйте его, проблем никаких. Но в коллекциях значительно больше возможностей найти что-то действительно подходящее под задачи.

Классический алгоритм выбора коллекции (для *Java* под рукой нет, у кого есть замените, но идея от этого не изменится):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом массивы здесь находятся в блоке `array`. `vector` - это уже динамический массив ближе к `ArrayList<>`.

Безусловно *любой* алгоритм  и *любую* структуру из коллекций можно реализовать самому, но зачем?..

Непосредственно по вопросам:

> Чем коллекции лучше массивов?

В них больше функционала, делать это над массивами зачастую нецелесообразно 
(или плохое качество кода или долго реализовывать или требуют хорошего понимания алгоритмов).

> Когда лучше использовать массивы, чем коллекции?

Когда нужно хранить набор данных фиксированного размера. Смотри картинку с выбором.

Answer (score 7):

Давайте по порядку:

1. Чем коллекции лучше массивов?

Если вы работаете с примитивными типами, и не хотите тратить время на `boxing/unboxing`, то массивы предпочтительнее. Но если вы используете обычные классы, то лучше воспользоваться коллекциями, потому что массивы коварианты. Т.е. с ними легко написать не `type-safe` код.

Например, такой:

```
 Integer[] a1 = new Integer[10];
 Object[] a2 = a1;
 a2[0] = "привет ArrayStoreException!";
```

При этом компилятор ни разу не скажет, что это не правильно.

2. В чем преимущества коллекций над массивами?

Все зависит сильно от ваших задач. В коллекциях много различных структур данных, с разными свойствами. Например, `Set` - множество уникальных элементов, `TreeSet` - множество уникальных отсортированных элементов,  `List` - список, сохраняющий порядок вставки, и т.д. Тут нельзя дать определенный ответ, тут скорее вопрос о целесообразности применения. Если вам в какой то момент не будет хватать простого массива, то смело используйте `collection`.

3. Когда лучше использовать массивы, чем коллекции?

см. пункт 2.