# Для чего нужны коллекции в программировании?

Tags: java, list, коллекции, очередь

Для чего нужны коллекции? Списки, очереди, наборы?

Что в них можно хранить?

Можете пожалуйста дать ссылки примеров работы с коллекциями?

Comment: был похожий вопрос, почитайте немного станет понятнее http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561489/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Коллекции нужны для хранения множества объектов. Неплохое краткое руководство есть [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/237043/). Ну а вообще, для понимания работы коллекций необходимо бы почитать соответствующую главу в одной из классических книг по Java (да можно и без привязки к языку, но лучше с ней).

Comment: Классическая [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/237043/) на Хабре о коллекциях в целом.
Очень простые примеры того, что можно делать с коллекциями, но на английском: [раз](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/collections/java-util-collections-example/) и [два](http://www.java-examples.com/collections)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Что-то какой-то ответ предыдущего оратора слишком краткий, на мой вкус.  И статья на мой вкус не самая "вкусная".

> Для чего нужны коллекции? > списки,очереди,и наборы?

Очень просто - в коллекциях вы можете хранить объекты, практически любые.
Коллекции, это в том или ином приближении - динамические массивы, то есть массив который увеличивает свою длину, когда вы записываете новый объект.
К примеру, пусть вы пишите какой-нибудь обработчик картинок. Вы разумеется не знаете, сколько к вам в хранилище придёт снимков. Может быть нуль, может быть сто. Вы создаёте динамический список `ArrayList` и в нём храните то, что нужно.

Очередь с приоритетом часто используется для сортировки массива и для нахождения максимума\минимума.

Набор `set` - упорядоченное множество. Коллекции `Set` предназначены для хранения множества не повторяющихся объектов. Таким образом при добавление двух элементов с одинаковым значением в коллекцию, с интерфейсом `Set`, коллекции это воспримут за один элемент.  Каждый объект который вы добавите в коллекцию `set`  получит свой уникальный хэш-код, то есть строку по которой можно будет осуществить доступ к нему. Пример использования `Set` - пусть вы пишите базу данных по автомобильным номерам. Там не допустима ситуация, когда у двух машин один номер. Именно set по скорости работы (поиска и добавления) в этом плане окажется эффективнее других структур данных.

> Что в них можно хранить(и как?примеры)?

Про то как примерно хранить. Я давал нечто, похожее на ответ [в другом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583526/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-liststring/583571#583571).

Если вам вздумается экономить время в изучении вопроса с коллекциями, я шибко рекомендую посмотреть примеры в формате скринкастов на ютьюбе. ИМХО это отличные практические занятия для каждого. Мне больше всего по коллекциям понравилось это:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBaei16Yy4s (и после уроков пять)

К слову должен сказать, что это не единственные хорошие уроки по коллекциям на ютьюбе, есть ещё куча не плохих.

**PS**. Если материал кажется вам не полным вы можете задать дополнительные вопросы, типа примеров работы c каждой конкретной коллекцией. Ибо в одном ответе довольно трудно всё кратко прояснить.

Comment: Очень понятно все разъяснили! К сожалению я только сейчас увидел ваш ответ, когда уже все давно понял((, но ответ очень понятный и разжеванный!